# How to merge a repo into a parent directory repo

Tags: git

I have researched but not found what I'm looking for.  I am on git 1.7.12 and at the moment I cannot update to aything newer.

I create a repo at /path/parent/repoA.  Later I decide I would rather have the repo at /path/parent.

I understand I could use submodules but that doesn't work the way I expect.  If I change /path/parent/repoA/file1.txt, when I do

```
git status
```

at /path/parent it just tells me I have changes in repoA.

```
git add -u repoA/*
```

Won't pick it up the modified file.  No manner of git add resolves this.  I tried

```
git add -u repoA/*
git remote add repoA repoA
git fetch repoA
git merge repoA/master
git remote remove repoA
```

and that kinda worked but ended up with a submodule.  How can I merge repoA into /path/parent as if /path/parent/repoA is no longer a repo?

I do not want to move any files, I just want to make it so /path/parent is the one and only repo.

Answer (score 0):

Move the content of repository name `repoA` into it's parent directory using `git mv`

- `cd /path/parent/`.
- `git mv -r /path/parent/repoA/* /path/parent/`.

Comment: Thank you.  Will this keep my directory structure the same?  I do not want to actually move the files.  What I want is I make a change to  
<br/><p>

- `/path/parent/repoA/file1.txt`

and I do


- `host:/path/parent $ git status`

It tells me repoA/file1.txt has been modified and if I do


- `git add -u */*`

It will pick up repoA/file1.txt  Thanks.